# Coloring Google's Android Sliding Tabs

Tags: java, android, xml

I have successfully used Google's Sliding Tabs code in my project. (Sample project can be found here: http://developer.android.com/samples/SlidingTabsBasic/index.html)  This is what I have so far:
[image: Sliding Tab Layout Screenshot]

Unfortunately, I am unable to figure out how to color the tabs. As shown below, I have found the method to color the indicator, but I want the entire tab to be colored. My ultimate goal is to emulate the tab layout that YouTube uses:
[image: YouTube Screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your SlidingTabLayout class, you should have the below constructor

```
public SlidingTabLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle)
```

Then use the following statement to set the background color of tabs

```
this.setBackgroundColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.red));
```

You need to define the color (e.g., red) in your colors.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <color name="red">#cc0000</color>
</resources>
```

Comment: Since you were able to answer this, you may be able to answer another question of mine similar to this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31779520/googles-android-sliding-tabs-layout