# Google's Android Sliding Tabs Layout

Tags: java, android, xml

I have successfully used Google's Sliding Tabs code in my project. (Sample project can be found here: http://developer.android.com/samples/SlidingTabsBasic/index.html)  This is what I have so far:
[image: Sliding Tab Layout Screenshot]

Unfortunately, I am unable to figure out how to make the tabs take up the entire bar. As shown below, they are taking up only approximately half the screen. I considered changing the padding, but I don't want to hard code it because of varying screen sizes. My ultimate goal is to emulate the tab layout that YouTube uses:
[image: YouTube Screenshot]

Comment: check this http://www.android4devs.com/2015/01/how-to-make-material-design-sliding-tabs.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably find the **setDistributeEvenly** method cannot be resolved if you use the sample code from

http://developer.android.com/samples/SlidingTabsBasic/src/com.example.android.common/view/SlidingTabLayout.html

Then in the **createDefaultTabView** method of your **SlidingTabLayout** class, add the following line before returning the textView

```
textView.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1.0f));
```

Answer (score 1):

Use Google IO [SlidingTabLayout](https://github.com/google/iosched/blob/b3c3ae2a5b41e28c07383644d78e5c076288322f/android/src/main/java/com/google/samples/apps/iosched/ui/widget/SlidingTabLayout.java) and [SlidingTabStrip](https://github.com/google/iosched/blob/b3c3ae2a5b41e28c07383644d78e5c076288322f/android/src/main/java/com/google/samples/apps/iosched/ui/widget/SlidingTabStrip.java) and call `setDistributeEvenly(true)` and it will create the same layout as the youtube one

Answer (score 1):

set this property as true in `SlidingTabLayout`

```
 mSlidingTabLayout.setDistributeEvenly(true);
```